# How to compile dcp2icc?

Tags: make, gnu-make

After trying for hours I am [unable to compile](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/issues/1) [dcp2icc-0.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcp2icc/) on Linux. With a simple [Makefile added to the original code](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/commit/634ca920b75b89bc233562ea20ff27e519448093) it fails as follows:

```
g++ -o build/XMP/source/XMPCore/ExpatAdapter.o -c -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Ifixes/XMP-Toolkit -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/build -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FormatSupport -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/third-party/MD5 -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/public/include XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/ExpatAdapter.cpp
In file included from XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/ExpatAdapter.cpp:10:0:
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/XMPCore_Impl.hpp: In function 'bool IsPathPrefix(XMP_StringPtr, XMP_StringPtr)':
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/XMPCore_Impl.hpp:371:28: error: 'strlen' is not a member of 'std'
  XMP_StringLen prefixLen = std::strlen(prefix);
                            ^
```

This I understand is because some default includes were removed. I tried [including everything that the files were missing](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/commit/853483a365434470e7ce31394a233adc6075a92b) (`cstdlib`, `inttypes.h`, `limits.h`, `cstring`), but:

```
g++ -o build/XMP/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers/ASF_Handler.o -c -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Ifixes/XMP-Toolkit -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/build -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FormatSupport -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/third-party/MD5 -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/public/include XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers/ASF_Handler.cpp
In file included from XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/XMPFiles_Impl.hpp:24:0,
                 from XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers/ASF_Handler.hpp:13,
                 from XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers/ASF_Handler.cpp:10:
fixes/XMP-Toolkit/LargeFileAccess.hpp:21:13: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int LFA_FileRef'
 typedef int LFA_FileRef;
             ^
```

I tried [forcing the type declaration to `void *`](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/commit/e42830ffd7a19a99896547c6180d355b06445dfd) (thanks Howard!):

```
g++ -o build/XMP/source/common/LargeFileAccess.o -c -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Ifixes/XMP-Toolkit -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/build -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FormatSupport -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/third-party/MD5 -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/public/include XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common/LargeFileAccess.cpp
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common/LargeFileAccess.cpp: In function 'void LFA_Close(LFA_FileRef)':
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common/LargeFileAccess.cpp:575:20: error: cast from 'LFA_FileRef {aka void*}' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   int descr = (int)file;
                    ^
```

I tried [compiling using 32-bit mode](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/commit/656b8a978e27ddfaf7f415bbf11ce632752bc28c):

```
g++ -o build/XMP/source/XMPCore/XMPCore_Impl.o -c -m32 -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Ifixes/XMP-Toolkit -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/build -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/common -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPFiles/FormatSupport -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/third-party/MD5 -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/public/include XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/XMPCore_Impl.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_algo.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/algorithm:62,
                 from XMP-Toolkit-SDK-4.4.2/source/XMPCore/XMPCore_Impl.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/cstdlib:178:10: error: expected unqualified-id before '__int128'
   inline __int128
          ^
```

What do I need to do to make this compile? Is this approach even sound?

Comment: Go back to when `LFA_FileRef` had a conflicting definition. That probably means you missed a few places when adding default header includes, or need some include guards.